# Find an expression of a random variable given its distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $([0,1),\mathbb{B}[0,1),\lambda)$ be a probability space, where $\mathbb{B}[0,1)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1)$, and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $X,Y:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be two random variables in the probability space, such that $X\sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$, where $\lambda>0$. Find expressions for the measurable functions $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$.

---

First thing I noticed is that clearly, the expressions are not unique. My goal is to find the simplest ones. I think I managed to do it with $X$. Since $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$, then its CDF is $F_X(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x},\forall x \geq 0$. Luckily, $F_X(x)$ is invertible on $[0,\infty)$:

$$F_X^{-1}(\omega)=-\frac{\ln(1-\omega)}{\lambda},\quad\forall\omega\in[0,1)$$

And $F_X^{-1}$ is invertible on $[0,1)$. So clearly, if I choose $X(\omega)=F_X^{-1}(\omega)$, then:

$$\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(F_X^{-1}(\omega)\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(\omega\leq F_X(x))=\lambda([0,F_X(x)])=F_X(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$$

Since $F_X(x)$ is monotonic and $F_X(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}({\lambda})$ as desired. I tried to do the same thing with $Y$, but the problem is, I have no idea how to invert its CDF $F_Y(k)$, which is given by:

$$F_Y(k)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$$

Pretty sure it's not invertible, actually. Maybe there's an other way. I couldn't think of one, unfortunately.

Thanks!

Comment: I notice you deleted your most recent question about prob of Gaussian random variables. Did you figure out what happened there? I am interested in knowing @Amit

Comment: @Jellyfish Yes I did, it was a silly mistake. I was missing a $1/2$ somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $m$ for Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ since you have used $\lambda$ with two meanings.

Since $e^{-\lambda} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {\lambda^{n}} {n!}=1$ there is a partition $\{A_0,A_1,\cdots \}$ of $[0,1]$ by intervals such that $m(A_n)=e^{-\lambda}\frac {\lambda^{n}} {n!}$ for each $n$. If $Y=n$ on $A_n$, $n=0,1,2,\cdots$  then $Y$ is a r.v. taking non-negative integer values and $P(Y=n)=m(A_n)=e^{-\lambda}\frac {\lambda^{n}} {n!}$ so $Y \sim Poiss(\lambda)$.

Comment: I see. So basically I need to find $A_n$, and then $Y(\omega)$ would be a sum of indicator functions? (I would need to construct the sum cleverly such that $Y=n$ on $A_n$)

Comment: $Y= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}n I_{A_n}$ . This is well defined because $(A_n)$ is partition of the interval: each point belongs to exactly one of the sets $A_n$. @AmitZach

Comment: Let $t_n=e^{-\lambda}\frac {\lambda^{n}} {n!}$. Take $A_0=[0,t_0), A_2=[t_0,t_0+t_1),A_2=[t_0+t_1, t_0+t_1+t_2),...$. @AmitZach

Comment: Thanks so much!